# Proof of Lipschitz continuity of Wasserstein distance in WGAN paper

Tags: lipschitz-functions, wasserstein

I'm reading the Wasserstein GAN paper(https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875)
by Martin Arjovsky et al.
My question is about the proof of the statement 2 of Theorem 1 in the paper.
Please see the appendix C. The proof goes as follows. The part I don't understand is $\color{red}{\text{colored in red}}$.

> (...)
> Now let $g$ be locally Lipschitz.
> Then, for a given pair $(\theta, z)$
> there is a constant $L(\theta, z)$
> and an open set $U$ such that $(\theta, z) \in U$,
> such that for every $(\theta', z') \in U$
> we have
> $$
> \text{(Equation 1)} \quad \quad \quad
> \|g_\theta(z) - g_{\theta'}(z')\|
> \ \le \ %
> L(\theta, z) \ (\|\theta - \theta'\| + \|z - z'\|).
> $$
> $\color{red}{\text{By taking expectations and } z' = z \text{ we have}}$
> $$
> \text{(Equation 2)} \quad \quad \quad
> \mathbb E_z [\|g_\theta(z) - g_{\theta'}(z)\|]
> \ \le \ %
> \|\theta - \theta'\| \ %
> \mathbb E_z [L(\theta, z)]
> $$
> whenever $(\theta', z) \in U$.
> (...)

**Why I don't understand the red part:**
According to the proof,
the equation 1 holds for $(\theta',\ z') \in U$,
with the set $U$ dependent to the choice of $z$.
But we have to integrate equation 1 on $\mathcal Z$ to get equation 2.
This means $z$ varies, so $U$ does.
Hence, during the integration,
we cannot let $\theta'$ fixed since its range varies.

So **my question** is that whether I am wrong or not. Don't we need an additional assumption here?

If not, then could someone explain more about the red part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that their argument is correct, but I totally understand your confusion about the sentence in red. It would have been clearer if they had instead written *"By taking $z' =z$ and applying expectation on both sides we have..."*.

Indeed, let $(\theta,z)$ be a fixed pair. By local Lipschitzness of $g$, we know that there exists an open neighborhood of $(\theta,z)$, which we denote $U\equiv U(\theta,z)$, and a local Lipschitz constant $L\equiv L(\theta,z)$ such that
$$ \|g_\theta(z) - g_{\theta'}(z')\|
\ \le \ %
L(\theta, z) \ (\|\theta - \theta'\| + \|z - z'\|)\  \text{ for all }(\theta',z')\in U(\theta,z)\tag{Eq. 1}$$

Because $(\text{Eq. 1})$ is true for all $(\theta',z')\in U(\theta,z) $, it is in particular true for the pair $(\theta',z) $ where $\theta'$ is such that $(\theta',z')\in U(\theta,z)$ for some $z'$. Indeed, I'm sure you can convince yourself that if $(\theta',z')\in U(\theta,z) $, then $(\theta',z)\in U(\theta,z) $ as well.

From this it follows
$$  \|g_\theta(z) - g_{\theta'}(z)\|
\ \le \ %
L(\theta, z) \ \|\theta - \theta'\| \  \text{ for all }\theta'\in U_z(\theta)\tag{Eq. 1'}$$
Where $U_z(\theta) := \{\theta' : (\theta',z')\in U(\theta,z) \text{ for some } z'\}$. Now the result would follow by taking expectation with respect to $z$ in $(\text{Eq. 1'}) $, but the issue is that $U_z(\theta)$ depends on $z$. The only way around it is to restrict $\theta'$ to the neighborhood $U(\theta)$ defined as $U(\theta):=\{\theta' : (\theta',z)\in U(\theta,z)\text{ for all } z\} $, such that we have
$$  \|g_\theta(z) - g_{\theta'}(z)\|
\ \le \ %
L(\theta, z) \ \|\theta - \theta'\| \  \text{ for all }\theta'\in U(\theta)\tag{Eq. 1''}$$
This is indeed the approach taken by the authors in their paper. Since $(\text{Eq. 1''}) $ is valid for all values of $z$, you can take expectations on both sides and conclude.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So I have to replace $z'$ by $z$, an then take expectation with $\theta' \in U(\theta)$. But I have one more little question; is $U(\theta)$ always nonempty? The set $U=U(\theta, z)$ may not contain a subset of form $\{\theta'\}\times \mathcal Z$, and in this case $U(\theta)$ becomes empty. Maybe I misread something.

Comment: This is a valid concern and I wondered about it when writing my answer too. Now that I had a closer look at the paper, it seems like $\mathcal Z$ is some kind of metric/normed space and $\theta\in \mathbb R^d$, in which case the natural topology on $\mathcal Z\times \mathbb R^d$ is the one induced by the  metric $d((\theta,z),(\theta',z')) := \|\theta-\theta'\|_{\mathbb R ^d} + \|z-z'\|_{\mathcal Z} $. In particular, since a neighborhood of $(\theta,z) $ is always (contained in) an $\epsilon$-ball around $(\theta,z)$, you can convince yourself that $U(\theta)$ is indeed never empty